# [DataTables ][columnFilter] thead:after doesn't work

Tags: datatables

i try to use columFilter with sPlaceHolder: "thead:after"

i use :
jquery 1.8.1
datatables 1.9.3
columnFilter 1.5.0

my table is :

```
<table align="center" border="1" id="tatable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Numero de la prise</th>
                <th scope="col">Description</th>
                <th scope="col">Piece</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
// a lot of data
</tbody>
</table>
```

my jquery code for initialisation is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tatable').dataTable({
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "iDisplayLength":50    
}).columnFilter({
    sPlaceHolder: "thead:after",
    aoColumns :[
        {type: "text"},
        {type: "text"},
        {type: "text"},
        {type: "text"}
    ]
    }
);
});
```

this code display 2 row on header and inputs is on bottom of the table ... WHY ???

(link of jquery plugins )
http://www.datatables.net and 
http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html

Comment: I think the data should be between the thead and the tfoot tags

Answer (score 2):

I just googled this and learnt some of it, but i haven't come across a filter like yours, I have seen this: `head:before`
so shouldn't yours be:
`head:after`?

PS: i've used "head" and NOT "thead"